# Firebase Storage authentication issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am trying to download images from Firebase storage but I am getting errors.

```
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanu: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
```

However, I have my rules set up like this:

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/<myappnameredacted>.appspot.com/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are not like in the [Firebase Storage Security Rules Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start).

For make all your files public (for anyone), use :

```
// Anyone can read or write to the bucket, even non-users of your app.
// Because it is shared with Google App Engine, this will also make
// files uploaded via Google App Engine public.

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

For make all your files readable (for anyone), use :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also make only your image readable / writable, see the [Firebase Storage Security Rules Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start).